# Order record array by unique occurances

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having difficulty piecing together some logic to order a numpy record array by unique occurrences, such that the first record occurs most frequently and the last as least frequent.

Consider four records with one duplicate:

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([('A', 1), ('B', 3), ('A', 2), ('B', 3)],
              dtype=[('c1', '|S1'), ('c2', 'i')])
```

My ideal result is this:

```
[('B', 3) ('A', 1) ('A', 2)]
```

(For SQL fans: `SELECT c1, c2 FROM ar GROUP BY c1, c2 ORDER BY count(*) DESC;`)

This is what I've tried using [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
uar, inv = np.unique(ar, return_inverse=True)
print uar  # [('A', 1) ('A', 2) ('B', 3)]
print inv  # [0 2 1 2]
print np.bincount(inv)  # [1 1 2]
```

but this is where I'm lost in piecing togher any logic to sort `uar` according the decreasing counts from `np.bincount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> uar[np.bincount(inv).argsort()[::-1]]
array([('B', 3), ('A', 2), ('A', 1)],
      dtype=[('c1', '|S1'), ('c2', '<i4')])
```

Argsort will find the indices sorted from lowest to highest:

```
>>> np.bincount(inv).argsort()
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.bincount(inv).argsort()[::-1] #Reverse.
array([2, 1, 0])
```

You can use lexsort to increase the control of the sorting:

```
uar[np.lexsort((uar['c2'],np.bincount(inv)*-1))]
array([('B', 3), ('A', 1), ('A', 2)],
      dtype=[('c1', '|S1'), ('c2', '<i4')])
```

I probably need to double check this in the morning to make sure that its stable.

Comment: spot on; works perfectly with a more complicated real-world case